# How to hit google geocoding api with signed request through GeoApiContext?

Tags: google-maps, unsigned, signed, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I am using google geocoding api to figure out pincode of a lat long and recently found that an unsigned request has a limit of 25,000 per day. I am not able to find how to send a signed request through the GeoApiContext, please help if you know, below is my code snippet:

```
    String googleApiKey = getGoogleApiKey();
    GeoApiContext geoApiContext = new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey(googleApiKey).build();
    LatLng latLng = buildLatLong(userLocation);
    GeocodingApiRequest geocodingApiRequest = GeocodingApi.newRequest(geoApiContext).latlng(latLng);
    long startTime = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
    try {
      GeocodingResult[] geocodingResult = geocodingApiRequest.await();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to *sign* **Geocoding API** requests when [using an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key) (as you are doing).

The daily limit of 25,000 *Unsigned requests (if URL signing secret is defined)* applies only to the *image* APIs (**Maps Static API** and **Street View Static API**) which are the only ones that allow [digitally sign your request with an API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/digital-signature).

If you really are seeing **per day** limits for the Geocoding API under https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/quotas?project= I would recommend you [contact Support](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/support#contact-maps-support) about it.